# Having issues accessing Parameter Store value from ECS Task with ExecutionRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-parameter-store

I'm trying to pass sensitive data to a container that runs in an ECS service. I have been following the AWS documentation for how to do this ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html)). I have done the following:

- define `my-param` in SSM Parameter Store
- create a TaskRole (see below)
- use the TaskRole in the Task's ExecutionRole
- add environment variable to container instance

Here is the task definition:

```
Description: >
  An IAM Role that gives tasks access to SSM Parameter store.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html

Resources:

  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ecs-task-role-${AWS::StackName}
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
        {
            "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "Service": [ "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" ]},
                "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
            }]
        }
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub ecs-task-role-${AWS::StackName}
          PolicyDocument: !Sub |
            {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "ssm:GetParameters"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/my-param"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }


Outputs:
  TaskRole:
    Description: An IAM Role that gives tasks read access to SSM Parameter store parameters.
    Value: !Ref TaskRole
```

Here's the Task Definition in which I use this role:

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: backend
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole <--- TaskRole is passed in as a parameter
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: backend
          Essential: true
          Image: !Ref ImageUrl
          MemoryReservation: 128
          Command:
            - '/start_prod.sh'
          Secrets: <-- here is where I'm trying to access the parameter
            - Name: MY_PARAM 
              ValueFrom: !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/my-param"
          Environment:
            - Name: GIT_SHA
              Value: !Ref GitSHA
```

In my `CloudFormation::Init` Metadata for the LaunchConfiguration, I have added the following:

```
            03_enable_awslogs_executionrole_override:
              command: echo ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE=true >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

When I update the stack, it seems to hang, and then eventually rolls back with a `failed to stabilize` error on the service in which I have a task that is trying to use the TaskRole I have defined.

The source code for the project is here: https://gitlab.com/verbose-equals-true/django-postgres-vue-gitlab-ecs

Answer (score 0):

I was simply using an out of date container agent. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html):

> For tasks that use the EC2 launch type, this feature requires that your container instance have version 1.22.0 or later of the container agent.

After updating my `LaunchConfiguration`, everything worked:

```
Parameters:

  ECSAMI:
    Description: AMI ID
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux/recommended/image_id
    Description: The Amazon Machine Image ID used for the cluster, leave it as the default value to get the latest AMI

  ContainerInstances:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref ECSAMI
      ...
```